# How to compare two large dataframes to check new entries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two pandas dataframes (for half 1 of 2020 and half 2 of 2020) with customers, as well as the products they bought. Is there an efficient way to find out which customers bought something in half 2, which they had not bought in half 1?

h1_2020:

| Customer | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |

h2_2020:

| Customer | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 3 | A |

So the output based on the above two tables should be:

| Customer | Bought something new in half 2? |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

Comment: Is the set of customers the same for both dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.merge`. If you have new customers in h2_2020, they will be present in the final output:

```
>>> pd.merge(h1_2020, h2_2020, on=['Customer', 'Product'], indicator=True, how='right') \
      .query("_merge == 'right_only'") \
      .value_counts('Customer') \
      .reindex(set(h1_2020['Customer'].unique()).union(h2_2020['Customer'].unique()), fill_value=0)

Customer
1    0
2    1
3    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the set difference to compare the values

```
   # dfh1: Dataframe for h1 and dfh2 is the DataFrame for h2
   product_by_customer = dict()
   customers = df_h1['Customer'].unique()
   for customer in customers:
       products_in_h1 = set(dfh1[dfh1['customer']==customer]['product'].values)
       products_in_h2 = set(dfh2[dfh2['customer']==customer]['product'].values)
       product_by_customer[customer] = list(products_in_h2.difference(products_in_h1))
   print(product_by_customer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Join and then check which record comes from `h2_2020` only:

```
h1h2 = h1_2020.merge(h2_2020, how='outer', indicator=True)

#   Customer Product      _merge
#0         1       A        both
#1         1       B   left_only
#2         2       A   left_only
#3         3       A        both
#4         2       B  right_only
#5         3       C  right_only

(h1h2.groupby('Customer')['_merge']
     .agg(lambda g: g.eq('right_only').sum())
     .rename('Newly Bought')
     .reset_index())

#   Customer  Newly Bought
#0         1             0
#1         2             1
#2         3             1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the set of customers is the same for both data sets then you could do the following:

```
h2_2020 = h2_2020.drop_duplicates()
h1_2020 = h1_2020.drop_duplicates()

h2_2020.groupby('Customer').apply(lambda x: len(x)) > h1_2020.groupby('Customer').apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed dataframe h2_2020 adding customer 4 in case of entry of new customer

```
# module

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make a dataset

h1_2020={'customer':[1,1,2,3],
         'product':'A B A A'.split()
         }

h2_2020={'customer':[1,2,3,3,4],
         'product':'A B C A A'.split()
         }

h1_2020=pd.DataFrame(h1_2020)
print(h1_2020)
h2_2020=pd.DataFrame(h2_2020)
print(h2_2020)
```

so my result has other column indicating if a customer is new customer in half 2 or not.

```
# drop_duplicates

dh1_2020=h1_2020.drop_duplicates()
dh2_2020=h2_2020.drop_duplicates()

# append and drop_duplicates to see what products customers bought during year

a=dh2_2020.append(dh1_2020).drop_duplicates().sort_values(['customer','product'])
print(a)

# check whether customers bought new product in half 2 

check=a.merge(dh1_2020, on=['customer','product'],indicator=True,how='outer')
print(check) 
# => 'left_only' means that the customer bought new product in half 2, but customer 4 is new customer in half 2

'''
#make a dummy column indicating a customer bought new product or not 
and the other dummy column indicating if a customer is new customer in half 2 or not

'''
m1=pd.DataFrame(dh1_2020.customer.drop_duplicates())
print(m1)
m2=check.loc[check['_merge']=='left_only',['customer','_merge']].drop_duplicates()
print(m2)

whatwewant=m1.merge(m2,on='customer',how='outer', indicator='new_customer_hf2')
whatwewant['_merge']=1*(whatwewant['_merge']=='left_only')
whatwewant['new_customer_hf2']=1*(whatwewant['new_customer_hf2']=='right_only')
print(whatwewant)

#   customer  _merge  new_customer_hf2
#0         1       0                 0
#1         2       1                 0
#2         3       1                 0
#3         4       1                 1
```